# compute sum for space string column

Tags: r

I have dataframe that contains space in the column name

```
df <- data.frame("a 1"=c("jan","jan" , "feb"),"t t" =c(10,10,1))
colnames(df) <- c("a 1","t t")
```

I want to sum the "t t" column on the basis of "a 1"
I tried this

```
df %>% group_by("a 1") %>% summarise(tx = sum("t t"))
```

the expected result is a dataframe having

```
  a 1    t t
  jan     20
  feb     1
```

Comment: Use backticks : `df %>% group_by(\`a 1\`) %>% summarise(tx = sum(\`t t\`))`

Comment: Don't use quotes when piping, use backticks (because you have space in your names). i.e. ```df %>% group_by(`a 1`) %>% summarise(tx = sum(`t t`))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
df %>% group_by(`a 1`) %>% summarise(tx = sum(`t t`))
```